# Variable must have at least two levels (R code)

Tags: r, r-factor

My training data looks like this:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   2
1   1   2   1
1   1   2   1
1   1   2   2
1   1   2   2
1   2   1   1
1   2   1   1
1   2   1   2
1   2   1   2
1   2   2   1
1   2   2   2
2   1   1   1
2   1   1   1
2   1   1   2
2   1   1   2
2   1   2   1
2   1   2   1
2   1   2   2
2   1   2   2
2   2   1   1
2   2   1   2
2   2   2   1
2   2   2   2
2   2   2   2
```

And my test data:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   2   1
1   1   2   2
1   1   1   1
2   1   2   2
```

I did fitting using:

```
dag <- model2network("[A][B][C|A:B][D|A:B:C]")
training <- bn.fit(dag, trainingData, method = "mle", keep.fitted = TRUE)
```

And I am trying to predict values for column D using:

```
predicted = predict(training, node = "D", data = testData,  method = "parents", prob = FALSE)
```

But I get the error

> Error in check.data(data, allow.levels = TRUE) :    variable B must
>   have at least two levels.

How do I fix this? I was of the view that test data does not need to have all levels that are included in the training data - in fact, shouldn't it be possible to predict even if the test data has one instance only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your variables are all encoded as `factor` they "have" a list of factor levels. When you create `training` you have `1` and `2` in column B, and the factor levels are (implicitly, in the background) set to c(`1`, `2`). But when you create `testData` you only have `1` in column B, and the factor levels are (implicitly, in the background) set to only `1`.

We can fix this by explicitly stating that `testData$B` has the levels `c(1, 2)` even though only `1` appears in the data.

```
testData$B <- factor(testData$B, levels=c(1, 2))
```

## Edit:

Fixed the stupid mistake where I wrote `training` while I totally intended to write `testData`

Comment: I had already converted both the training and test data into factors using this code:
`datacols <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")`

`for (i in 1:ncol(testData)) {`
     `testData[,datacols[i]] <- factor(testData[,datacols[i]])`
 `}`

Comment: Did you try the answer I gave you? Did it not resolve the error? The conversion you show in this comment is exactly the reason for the error.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. The code you've shared gives this error: `Error in check.dnode(value, node = name) :` 
`the conditional probability distribution of node B must be a table, a matrix or a multidimensional array.`

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. What is the output of str(testData) before you do the suggested re-leveling of the factor and after?

Comment: Wait, when I run your code on the **test data** the error goes away. Seems logically correct since it's the test data which didn't seem to have all the levels.

Comment: Exactly. That makes a lot more sense ;)

Comment: Yes, problem resolved. But please edit your answer to show testData instead of training

Comment: Oh.. so sorry, I wasn't aware that I used the wrong variable name. That's a bad mistake to make! (I fixed it)